# Send request parameter from javascript to portletRequest object

Tags: jquery, portal, websphere-portal

I have a JSR 168 Portlet deployed in IBM Portal Server that has a jsp with the following code...

```
<a href="
      <portlet:renderURL>
            <portlet:param name="itemNumber" value="<%=sessionBean.getItems()[i].getItemNumber()%>"/>
      </portlet:renderURL>"><%=sessionBean.getItems()[i].getItemNumber()%>
</a>
```

I am now trying to move this code from my jsp into my jquery javascript but I don't think placing portlet:renderURL will give me the right result. I tried that and it left me with that custom tag as plain text in the source.

How can I get the value of portlet:renderURL variable into my javascript? . Or perhaps the better question is what is the correct way to pass a request parameter from javascript to the portletRequest object.

**--Update--**

Well here is an update on what I was able to achieve. I figured out today that I could do the following in my jsp...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        var params = ({
            portletUrl : '<%= renderResponse.createRenderURL() %>'                  
        });
    init(params);
    });
```

And then in my jquery externalised file I could do...

```
var portletUrl = null;

$()ready(function(){
   var myUrl = '<a href="'+portletUrl + "?itemNumber=" + data+'">' + data + '</a>';
}

function init(params) { 
    portletUrl = params.portletUrl;
}
```

It seems to work but I can't help thinking this is not the recommended method. Especially because to get the parameter I need to cast the portlet request to a http request.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portlet tags can be rendered in jsp only. So,I feel you can assign the rendered the url with parameter values to a global javascript variable and use it across.